# Flex application to component?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, components, flexbuilder, mxml

I have an application built in Flex Builder 3.  It has a fair amount of mxml and as3 code which uses some other custom compenents.  I have looked at the documentation on building components which shows how to make a simple mxml or action script component that extends something like a combobox, but I'm lost as to how to take a whole existing and independently functioning Application and turn it into a reusable component.

Basically, I'd just like to create multiple instances of this app inside of another flex project.

Anyone able to provide a little guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy thing to do is to swap the Application mxml tag with a VBox tag...thus making it act like a component.

e.g. If this were your application:

```
//Foo.mxml
<mx:Appliction xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Label text = "foo" />
</mx:Appliction>
```

change it to:

```
//Foo.mxml
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:Label text = "foo" />
</mx:VBox>
```

and then you can do something like this:

```
//App.mxml
<mx:Appliction 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:local="your.package.scheme.*"
>
    <local:Foo />

</mx:Appliction>
```

You may have to make some public properties if you need to pass in any data to the component...

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want some "parent" Flex application to embed several instances of this autonomous child application, then you should see Adobe's ["Embedding Asset Types"](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html) documentation, which describes how to embed one SWF file in another.

From the documentation:

> You typically embed a Flex application
>   when you do not require the embedding
>   application to interact with the
>   embedded application. If the embedding
>   application requires interactivity
>   with the embedded application, you
>   might consider implementing it as a
>   custom component, rather than as a
>   separate application.

If you *do* require interaction between the embedded application and the parent application, you can look into the [SWFLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_15.html) control.